# How can I store a file in a specific block of HD in java?

Tags: java

I want to write a simple database in java using btree and I have to store every node of btree in a specific block of HD and store the address in the node .... How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Funny, this doesn't _sound_ simple if you're concerned with something as low-level as disk blocks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a clue what you are talking of? Because that would pretty much destroy the file system on the drive, so it would only work on a RAW drive. Most databases write to a specific position in a FILE, they do not bother with the layout of the platter.

Comment: This is a HUGE project - you'd basically need to implement some sort of raw file system, and write your database to use that.  Oracle used to do that (maybe they still do?), and they sure as hell didn't write it in Java.

Comment: I can see the idea sounds attractive because at first sight it's a simple solution to a hard problem.  Instead you could study how existing Java databases (Derby, H2, ...) manage storage and ensure performance, if your aim is to learn something.

Comment: I said that it's not complete database , I think it's better to say that " How Can I Store a file in a specific block of hard drive with system file help ? and also store the address of block ?"

Comment: In Oracle, the concept is called "raw device". By the way, that task is the job of the operating system not an application. To avoid such direct access, virtualization tools create large file on existing file systems to be used as a disk image but have decided not by-pass operating system. So avoid it, except if you are implementing a Java-based operating system ;)

Answer (score 3):

On Unixoids you can open the raw devices like `/dev/sda1` in the same way as any other file. Then you can read and write to that "file" using `RandomAcccessFile`.

But: Be **very** sure you **really** know what you do! The comments might give you a clue.